# How to change Rails route depending on REMOTE_USER

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4.1 application. I want to change how `/home` works depending on the environment variable `REMOTE_USER`.

I have this in my `routes.rb` file:

```
get "home" => Utility.home_page(ENV['REMOTE_USER'])
```

The function `Utility.home_page` returns one of `app1#home`, `app2#home`, or `helps#index` depending on the value of its argument.

However, it appears that `routes.rb` is only loaded once, so all users end up getting directed to the same application.

Comment: ENV variables are set for a server application, they are not set per request. Once a server is started, the `ENV['REMOTE_USER']`never changes and is the same for all requests and users.  If you have several applications, each of them has its own ENV variables and `routes.rb` file. How do you expect users get different responses if they request the same app with the same ENV variables and `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @chumakoff maybe the project have complex use cases depending on the configuration of each server. Regardless of case, what OP is asking for can be achieved easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible problems:

1. You are trying to fetch the `REMOTE_USER` value from ENV variables that are set for the server application, not per request. Once the server is started, the ENV['REMOTE_USER'] never changes and is the same for all requests and users.

   It looks like what you need is to fetch the value from the request environment: `request.env["REMOTE_USER"]`
2. The `Utility.home_page(ENV['REMOTE_USER'])` will be calculated only once, when the application is started. You need to use constraints with lambda expressions based on request.

The solution might be like this:

```
get "home", to: "app1#home", constraints: lambda { |request| Utility.home_page(request.env['REMOTE_USER']) == "app1#home" }

get "home", to: "app2#home", constraints: lambda { |request| Utility.home_page(request.env['REMOTE_USER']) == "app2#home" }

get "home", to: "helps#index", constraints: lambda { |request| Utility.home_page(request.env['REMOTE_USER']) == "helps#index" }
```

In this case I would change the `Utility` api to work like this:

```
get "home", to: "app1#home", constraints: lambda { |request| Utility.home_page?(:app1, request.env['REMOTE_USER']) }
get "home", to: "app2#home", constraints: lambda { |request| Utility.home_page?(:app2, request.env['REMOTE_USER']) }
get "home", to: "helps#index", constraints: lambda { |request| Utility.home_page?(:helps, request.env['REMOTE_USER']) }
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace the three `get "home"...` clauses with a single one that uses the output of `Utility.home_page(..)` for the `to:` parameter?

Comment: The use of `ENV['REMOTE_USER']` was the culprit.

Comment: I don't see another solution. Updated the answer to give you some another idea.

Answer (score 0):

`routes.rb` is actually a `ruby` file, so you can perform all the validations that you want there.

If you need to change **home** path depending on the value of an environment variable, you can do something like this in `routes.rb`:

```
if ENV['REMOTE_USER'] == 'foo'
  get "home" => 'app1#home'

elsif ENV['REMOTE_USER'] == 'bar'
  get "home" => 'app2#home'

end
```

Comment: ENV['REMOTE_USER'] will be the same for all requests and users. It is not set per request. Anyway, your `if-else` will run only once, when the application is started.

Comment: @chumakoff That's right. `ENV['REMOTE_USER']` is an environment variable and `routes.rb` is loaded once. If the OP wants to change the action of the route depending on which server is running his app, it will work. Otherwise, your answer is the correct approach.